# No-op element for a switch case in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'd like to use `case` in SwiftUI, but to not do anything (= don't output any view) in a certain case. In plain swift, I'd put `break` there, but in SwiftUI's view builder, this is apparently not allowed:

```
VStack {
  switch dayOrNight {
    case .day:
      Text("Daylight, yay!")
    case .night:
      break // produces error: Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder'
  }
}
```

Is there a 'no-op' element I could output instead?

Answer (score 2):

An [EmptyView()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/emptyview) should be used in such cases.

Comment: Why not use `let _ = ()`?